# Alerta para web em script c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web em asp.net e me deparei com um problema.

No retorno dos seus Catchs, eu retorno um erro através de um alert para o usuário assim:

```
try{
...
}
catch(Exception ex){
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Erro ao adicionar valores no banco.');</script>");
}
```

O problema é que eu também uso uma classe .cs que não está relacionada a nenhuma página, e ela também precisa retornar alguns erros, porém se eu uso "Response.Write" nada acontece.

Como eu poderia retornar esses erros no browser?

Já tentei as seguintes formas, mas não obtive sucesso:

- `Response.write`
- `page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`
- `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`

Comment: Como você está fazendo o uso do `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` ?

Comment: Eu usei assim: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Only alert Message');",true); conforme dito nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825165/javascript-alert-showmessage-from-asp-net-code-behind